# Can I pull an image down from a repo and save it locally as a different name?

Tags: images, container, podman, buildah

I can pull down an image with `podman pull`

```
podman pull alpine:3
```

This currently pulls the image down as,

```
REPOSITORY                TAG             IMAGE ID      CREATED         SIZE
docker.io/library/alpine  3               14119a10abf4  5 weeks ago     5.87 MB
```

Is there anyway to save that image for future reference as `localhost/foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`podman tag`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-tag.1.html):

```
podman tag alpine:3 localhost/foo
```

You can also save any local image by sha to a different name,

```
podman tag 0159f8576312 localhost/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to launch it into a container and commit it,

```
podman run -ti alpine:3 /bin/sh
podman commit $(podman container ls -lq) localhost/foo
```

Alternatively, you can change `buildah from` and `buildah commit` which doesn't require starting a container,

```
buildah commit $(buildah from alpine:3) localhost/foo
```

Not sure if there is a faster way.